# Equivalent for NSString writeToFile and archiveRootObject in Android ?

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, writetofile

On iOS I use these lines of code to store a large String (JSon)... How can I do the same on Android? What is a file place to put that string?
Thanks

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


//make a file name to write the data to using the
//documents directory:
NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/subscriptions", documentsDirectory];
[dataReply writeToFile:fullFileName atomically:NO];
```

And for save directly the array? Like this?

```
   fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/specialElements", documentsDirectory];
  [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:specialElements toFile:fullFileName];
```

specialElements is a NSMutableArray

Comment: All the information is given here
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try
{
    String path = "/data/data/"+getPackageName()+"/test.json";
    File file = getFileStreamPath(path); 
    if (!file.exists())
    {
      file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileOutputStream writer = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    writer.write(data.getBytes());//data is your json in String
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //exception
}
```

Along with the below permission in manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```